# Can't extract JSONResult

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I can't seem to unpack a string list from a JSONResult.

Here is the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetDescriptions(string incomingProjectName)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (SFEntities ctx = new SFEntities())
        {
            result = (from ct in ctx.SF_CLIENT_TASK
                      join cp in ctx.SF_CLIENT_PROJECT on ct.PROJECT equals cp.ID
                      where cp.NAMEX == incomingProjectName
                      select ct.DESCRIPTION).ToList();
        }

        return Json( result );
    }
```

And here is my ajax method:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/GetDescriptions",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{incomingProjectName : "projName"}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("msg: " + msg);  // [Object object]
            alert("msg: 2 string: " + msg.toString);    // function toString() { [native code] }
            var list = eval(msg);
            alert("list: " + list); // blank
            alert("list to string: " + list.toString);  // function toString() { [native code] }
            alert("list data: " + list.valueOf);    // valueOf() { [native code] }
            alert("msg[0]: " + msg[0]);     // undefined
            alert("list[0]: " + list[0]);   // undefined
        },
    });
```

In the debugger I can see the contents of result has a long list of items, but I don't seem them however I try to access it in the JavaScript.

Is there some kind of de-serialize or extract method I'm failing to call?

EDIT: This seems like it should be a boilerplate thing, but I haven't been able to google many examples of doing this for some reason ...

EDIT: Here is my final (working) code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/GetDescriptions",
        data: { incomingProjectName: projName },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert( "msg: " + msg );
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Failed: " + msg.status + ": " + msg.statusText);
        }
```

And here is the controller code:

```
    public JsonResult GetDescriptions(string incomingProjectName)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (SFEntities ctx = new SFEntities())
        {
            result = (from ct in ctx.SF_CLIENT_TASK
                      join cp in ctx.SF_CLIENT_PROJECT on ct.PROJECT equals cp.ID
                      where cp.NAMEX == incomingProjectName
                      select ct.DESCRIPTION).ToList();
        }

        return Json( result );
    }
```

Comment: Your result should be contained inside `msg.d`. Did you try doing `console.log(msg.d);` or `alert(msg.d);` ?

Comment: I don't think MVC uses the `.d` part.

Comment: What happens if you use `console.dir(msg)`? What do you see in the debugger? also, you do realize to invoke methods you must use parenthesis `()` right? `list.toString()` and `list.valueOf()`, although I doubt they'll tell you anything useful in this case anyway.

Comment: I tried the alert(msg.d) and it just said: [undefined] :(

Comment: Try removing the `contentType` and `dataType` properties. Your request is pretty straight forward and I don't think they are required. I've made calls like this in code plenty of times w/o specifying them. I have had problems when they were specified incorrectly.

Comment: @BNL: I tried removing the contentType and dataType properties. It didn't make things any worse ... but it didn't make them any better either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code with the following controller method and it worked without any problems.

```
public JsonResult Test()
{
    return Json(new List<string> {"a", "b"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/Test",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log("msg: " + msg);  // [Object object]
        console.log("msg: 2 string: " + msg.toString);    // function toString() { [native code] }
        var list = eval(msg);
        console.log("list: " + list); // blank on your code
        console.log("list to string: " + list.toString);  // function toString() { [native code] }
        console.log("list data: " + list.valueOf);    // valueOf() { [native code] }
        console.log("msg[0]: " + msg[0]);     // undefined on your code
        console.log("list[0]: " + list[0]);   // undefined on your code
    }
});
```

And the result of the success method:

```
msg: a,b
msg: 2 string: function toString() { [native code] }
list: a,b
list to string: function toString() { [native code] }
list data: function valueOf() { [native code] }
msg[0]: a
list[0]: a
```

I believe the problem is that your list is empty or there is a problem with the serializer. Try to see the Json results contents on debug mode.

Update:

To see the data returning from your controller action, please remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute and change your return statement to `return Json( result ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` on your code Then go to `http://yoursite/controllername/GetDescriptions?incomingProjectName=projName` to see the returning json.

Comment: Also, try using Fiddler to check the actual return value on the wire.

Comment: Huh ... added the "JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet" but it didn't fix it. I wonder if I have some kind of error in my routing setup or something.

Comment: `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is due to my ajax call not having any parameters, nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Hey, that was cool. The JSON looked right. It was basically something like: ["Task1", "Task2", ..., "TaskN"]. Got the same alerts, though :(

Comment: I also verified the above test, there is something going on that hasn't been described yet.

Comment: Now the parameter doesn't seem to be going through. The return line you used above does seem to return something sensible. This is strange. What did I do to stop the parameter from going across correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I  would remove [eval function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp), why is it there? If you have array you should be able to iterate trough it like so:

```
for(var m in msg)
{
    alert(m[i]);
}
```

Comment: The eval function is there because I'm trying anything at this point ;) For some reason the code you gave got skipped when I ran it. I guess it didn't see msg as iterable.

Comment: I would guess that your javascript didnt reload.

Comment: Can you send us what is returned in msg object?

Comment: I'm having trouble exposing the contents of msg. That's why there are so many different kinds of alerts. The javascript was reloaded because I added another alert to make sure it was reloaded and it was.

Comment: Use any kind of debuging file and break on success and when you point to msg variable you should be able to see its contents.

Comment: I added a break there, but it flies on past it. Breaking in JS seems to be unreliable in VS.

Comment: You can just add `debugger;` in your code and it should break reliably.

Comment: Any major browser today has web development tools where you can debug javascript.